# How can I find the xpath of an element located by link text?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I'm working with a webpage that has xpaths that change slightly whenever the page is first loaded. Is there a way that I can use a get attribute function or something similar to automatically get the dynamic part of the xpath and then use that xpath in the rest of the script.

Right now, I have it set up to let me input the xpath while the script is running via a manual firebug lookup and a raw_input, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Here's the html for the element:

```
<td id="_jsx_0_aa_jsx_16_jsx_9" class="jsx30matrixcolumn_cell" style="position: relative; width: 177px; height: 18px; padding: 2px 0px 0px 4px; vertical-align: top; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(76, 76, 76); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" jsxtype="cell" onblur="jsx3.GO('_jsx_0_aa').yp(event,this,'W3');" onfocus="jsx3.GO('_jsx_0_aa').yp(event,this,'tu');" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="jsx30matrixcolumn_cell_value" style="position: relative; height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; text-decoration: underline;">Company Inc.  </div>
```

Comment: which part is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You could use -

```
//div[contains(., 'Company Inc.')]
```

or

```
//div[contains(text(),'Company Inc.')]
```

or

```
//div[text()='Company Inc.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this also :-

```
  //div[normalize-space(.)='Company Inc.']
```